# Typescript: Type X is missing the following properties of type Y length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. ts(2769)

Tags: html, angular, subscribe

Error:

Cannot assign a type argument `(resp: Producto []) => void` to the type parameter `(value: Object) => void`.

The `resp` and `value` parameter types are not supported.
The type `Object` can be assigned to very few types. Did you mean to actually use the type `any`?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MZta.png)

Comment: Try with `this.http.get<Producto[]>(`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` **But** it is better to use generic `this.http.get<Producto[]>` like this:

```
private cargarProductos(){
    this.http.get<Producto[]>('https://angular-htm1-25cf9.firebaseio.com/productos_idx.json')
        .subscribe((resp: Producto[]) => {
            console.log(resp);
            this.productos = resp;
            this.cargando = false;
        });
}
```

Comment: @ManuelEnrique Has your problem been solved? You can simply use generic `http.get` to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
  productos:Array<Producto>=[]

  private cargarProductos():any {
    this.http.get('https://angular-htm1-25cf9.firebaseio.com/productos_idx.json')
      .subscribe((resp:any)=>{
        console.log(resp);
        this.productos = resp;
        this.cargando = false;
      });
  }
```

- It's better to use the service component.